# Prove $\int_U |u|^2dx \le C(\int_U|Du|^2dx+\int_{\partial U}u^2dx)$ by divergence theorem?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How to prove $$\int_U |u|^2\,dx \le C\left(\int_U|Du|^2 \, dx+\int_{\partial U}u^2\,dx\right)?$$

The hint my teacher gives me is to apply the divergence theorem to $(0,\ldots,x_iu,0,\ldots,0)$, $1\le i\le n$.

I tried that and got $$\int_{\partial U} (0,\ldots,x_iu,0,\ldots,0)\cdot n \, dx) = \int_U u\,dx +\int_U x_i Du\,dx$$. Then I have thought for an hour and still have no idea about how to proceed next. Could someone kindly help? Thanks!

Comment: Are you working out of Evans? I proved this recently using a proof which is in exactly the same spirit as Evans' proof of the Poincare inequality for $H^1_0$. Basically, get a sequence where $\| f_k \|^2_{L^2(U)} = 1$ but $\| \nabla f_k \|_{L^2(U)} + \| f_k \|_{L^2(\partial U)} \to 0$; use Rellich compactness to get an $L^2$-convergent subsequence; then do some calculation to prove that the limit of the subsequence must actually be zero, which contradicts the fact that $\| f_k \|_{L^2(U)} = 1$.

Comment: Could it be that $U$ is the unit ball, or some particular domain? Also I think you have to apply the divergence theorem to the vector $xu^2$. At least this works when $U$ is the unit ball.

Answer (score 0):

Let: $$|u(x_1, ...,x_n)| = |u(a_1,x_2 ...) + \int^{x_1}_{a_1} {u_{x_1}} dx_1| $$ Using Cauchy-Schwarts 2 times: 
$$|u(x_1, ...,x_n)|^2 \leq 2|u(a_1,x_2 ...)|^2 + 2L\int^{L}_{0} |{u_{x_1}}|^2 dx_1$$ where L is a maximum diameter of the domain in $x_1$ direction.
Now integrating by $x_1$:
$$\int^{L}_{0}|u(x_1, ...,x_n)|^2dx_1 \leq 2L|u(a_1,x_2 ...)|^2 + 2L^2\int^{L}_{0} |{u_{x_1}}|^2$$
Future integration and summation over other components give:
$$\int_{\Omega}|u(x)|^2dx \leq C(\int_{\partial\Omega}|u(a)|^2da + \int_{\Omega} |{Du_{x}}|^2)$$, where C - is a constant that defined by maximum diameter of the domain.

Inequality is Poincare inequality with non-zero boundary conditions.
It plays supportive role in determining weak solutions in theory of viscous incompressible flow in 2D (Navier-Stockes problem).

Comment: It supports a lot of problems. A more basic case is the Poisson equation or heat equation with certain kinds of Robin conditions (such as $u+\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} = 0$).